# Odd performance issue when using an OR @Parameter IS NULL with a function

Tags: t-sql

I'm looking at legacy code because its performing very poorly.
I tracked the issue down to

```
DECLARE @Parameter AS VARCHAR(50) = '12345'
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE 
(
    MyIndexedField IN ( SELECT Value from fn_Function(@Parameter) )
    OR @Parameter ISNULL;
)
AND OtherCriteria = 'Something'
```

The query is wanting to pull all data from a table on a field that has a non clustered index. When I remove the OR @Parameter IS NULL it runs in under a second, but when I add the @Parameter IS NULL it takes 40s+.

If I replace the function with a literal, it runs in under a second.
Example

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE 
(
    MyIndexedField IN (  '12345' )
    OR @Parameter ISNULL;
)
AND OtherCriteria = 'Something'
```

Any idea whats going on, and a better way to rewrite this query?

This is being ran on SQL 2008

Thanks,

---

edit

I was able to to get around the problem but the solution was odd, see below.
Don't think this is the best solution, if you have any suggestions, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
DECLARE @Parameter AS VARCHAR(50) = '12345'
SELECT DISTINCT MyIndexedField
INTO #T
FROM MyTable WHERE @Parameter IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT Value FROM fn_Function(@Parameter)

SELECT *
FROM MyTable AS X
JOIN #T      AS T ON T.MyIndexedField = X.MyIndexedField
WHERE OtherCriteria = 'Something'
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the execution plans and knowing what the fn_Function function actually does it is hard to give conclusive advice, but a couple of ideas that would be worth exploring are:

1)  if you add OPTION (RECOMPILE) to the end of the statement then the optimizer will be able to 'see' the value of the @Parameter parameter and will therefore be able to optimize out the OR @Parameter IS NULL condition (for this particular input value) at the 'cost' of this statement having to be recompiled each time it is called (rather than being stored in the execution plan cache).  Depending on frequency of call / cost of compilation this may be a viable strategy

2)  depending on the complexity of the function fn_Function you may be able to re-write it in-line.  I can't know without seeing the function if it is a multi-statement or inline table valued function, which is relevant here.

Hope this gives some pointers on things to look at.